# Why is this assertion failing for my Scheme-based Brainfuck interpreter?

Tags: scheme, interpreter, fractals, turing-machines, brainfuck

I am writing a Brainfuck interpreter in Scheme (Chez Scheme). It seems like no matter which Brainfuck program I throw at it, it never works, and I cannot figure out why. I figured that I would try it with the code for Sierpinski's triangle (from [here](https://github.com/brain-lang/brainfuck/blob/master/examples/sierpinski.bf), tested [here](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/)), and a Hello World:

```lisp
(define hello-world "+[-[<<[+[--->]-[<<<]]]>>>-]>-.---.>..>.<<<<-.<+.>>>>>.>.<<.<-.")
(define sierpinski "++++++++[>+>++++<<-]>++>>+<[-[>>+<<-]+>>]>+[-<<<[->[+[-]+>++>>>-<<]<[<]>>++++++[<<+++++>>-]+<<++.[-]<<]>.>+[>>]>+]")
```

`(entry-point hello-world 100)` fails like this:

```lisp
|#\<
|(elem-at
   -1
   (255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0))
Exception: failed assertion (>= i 0) at line 7, char 10 of interpret.scm
```

When I use `elem-at`, the index argument is always the instruction pointer or the data pointer. It's so weird then that the pointer turns out to be less than 1 here.

`(entry-point sierpinski 20)` fails like this:

```lisp
|#\+
|(elem-at 20 (0 10 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 31 0))
|(elem-at 19 (10 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 31 0))
|(elem-at 18 (1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 31 0))
|(elem-at 17 (1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 31 0))
|(elem-at 16 (1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 31 0))
|(elem-at 15 (0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 31 0))
|(elem-at 14 (1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 31 0))
|(elem-at 13 (0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 31 0))
|(elem-at 12 (1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 31 0))
|(elem-at 11 (0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 31 0))
|(elem-at 10 (1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 31 0))
|(elem-at 9 (0 1 0 1 0 1 0 31 0))
|(elem-at 8 (1 0 1 0 1 0 31 0))
|(elem-at 7 (0 1 0 1 0 31 0))
|(elem-at 6 (1 0 1 0 31 0))
|(elem-at 5 (0 1 0 31 0))
|(elem-at 4 (1 0 31 0))
|(elem-at 3 (0 31 0))
|(elem-at 2 (31 0))
|(elem-at 1 (0))
|(elem-at 0 ())
Exception in car: () is not a pair
```

Again, there's another problem with a pointer, specifically `data-ptr`. This has me absolutely perplexed. My code is below. Does anyone know what is wrong with my interpreter?

```lisp
(define (token-list chars)
    (filter 
        (lambda (c) (memq c (list #\> #\< #\+ #\- #\. #\, #\[ #\])))
        (string->list chars)))

(trace-define (elem-at i lst)
    (assert (>= i 0))
    (if (zero? i) (car lst)
        (elem-at (sub1 i) (cdr lst))))

(define (change-byte! i cells modifier)
    (if (zero? i)
        (set-car! cells (modifier (car cells)))
        (change-byte! (sub1 i) (cdr cells) modifier)))

(define (print-status! cells instr instr-ptr data-ptr)
    (format #t "Cells = ~a, instr = ~a, instr ptr = ~a, data ptr = ~a\n"
        cells instr instr-ptr data-ptr))

(define (update-data-ptr instr data-ptr)
    (case instr
        (#\> (add1 data-ptr))
        (#\< (sub1 data-ptr))
        (else data-ptr)))

(define (ptr-after-jump program instr-ptr mover end)
    (if (eq? (elem-at instr-ptr program) end)
        instr-ptr
        (ptr-after-jump program (mover instr-ptr) mover end)))

(define (update-instr-ptr instr-ptr instr program cell)
    (add1
        (cond
            ((and (eq? instr #\[) (zero? cell))
                (ptr-after-jump program instr-ptr add1 #\]))
            ((and (eq? instr #\]) (not (zero? cell)))
                (ptr-after-jump program instr-ptr sub1 #\[))
            (else instr-ptr))))

(define (interpret program instr-ptr data-ptr cells)
    (when (not (= instr-ptr (length program)))
        (let ((instr (elem-at instr-ptr program)))
            (begin
                (print-status! cells instr instr-ptr data-ptr)
                (case instr
                    (#\+ (change-byte! data-ptr cells
                        (if (= (elem-at data-ptr cells) 255)
                            (lambda (_) 0) add1)))
                    (#\- (change-byte! data-ptr cells
                        (if (zero? (elem-at data-ptr cells))
                            (lambda (_) 255) sub1)))

                    (#\. (display (integer->char (elem-at data-ptr cells))))
                    (#\, (change-byte! data-ptr cells (lambda (_) (char->integer (read-char))))))

                (interpret
                    program
                    (update-instr-ptr instr-ptr instr program (elem-at data-ptr cells)); the problem may be around here
                    (update-data-ptr instr data-ptr)
                    cells)))))


(define (init-cells length buf)
    (if (zero? length) buf
        (init-cells (sub1 length) (cons 0 buf))))

(define (entry-point code tape-length)
    (interpret
        (token-list code)
        0 0; (floor (/ tape-length 2))
        (init-cells tape-length '())))
```

Comment: Your `ptr-after-jump` function doesn't look like it correctly handles nested loops. So that might be your problem or at least part of it. Generally, it'd be a good idea to test your functions individually to make sure that each one does what it's supposed to. That way you have a better idea of where to look when something goes wrong. It'd also make sense to come up with some more specific test cases to test your program on - small snippets that test specific features instead of whole programs.

Comment: On an unrelated note, accessing linked lists by index is very inefficient. The idiomatic way to implement Brainfuck in a functional language would be to use two lists for the tape (one containing everything to the left of the pointer in reverse order and the other containing the contents starting at the pointer), then you can perform all operations by just using `car`, `cdr` and `cons` on the lists. This approach would also make it easy to support an infinite tape.